# Create a dynamic selection of a range on a pivot table, for use in creating a chart

Tags: excel, vba

I'm automating a weekly report. I have a line chart for a data set that has three years of data.

I only care about the last 6 months.

Let's say I run this weekly report on August 27, 2019. My line chart should include March 2019 - August 2019 data. My Pivot table has my data set criteria and a filter 2019 selected, and all of the months. The number shown is an average. Which looks like this;
[image: Example of the Pivot Table showing 2019 data]

The code should use current Month Name, and select back to March. Showing this;
[image: Desired State]

```
Sub SelectCells()

Dim currentMonth As Single
Dim firstMonth As Single
Dim pastMonths As Single

pastMonths = 6

currentMonth = Month(Date) ' In this case: August
firstMonth = WorksheetFunction.Max(currentMonth - pastMonths, 1)

'select the work file
Windows("MyScrubbedData.xlsx").Activate
Range("B3").Select

Range(Range("C4").Offset(0, firstMonth), Range("C5").Offset(0, currentMonth - 1)).Select

End Sub
```

Which gives the desired selection. However, imagine running this for  March 2019. Then I need to select January 2019 - March 2019.

Should look like this;
[image: Desired if only 3 Months data]

The code is not built to handle that exception. So ends up looking like this;
[image: Actual Results.]

Ideally, I'd show Oct-2018 through March 2019 if I ran in March. But the the Pivot table results are really bad. So I'd be happy with going back 6 months, unless earlier in the year. In which case go back as far as we can go within that year.

Comment: Use the [`DateAdd` function](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dateadd.php). It would be something like `Dim startDate As Date; startDate = DateAdd("m", -6, Now())`

Comment: Might be easier to use a pivot chart, which plots all the pivot table's data, then filter the pivot table according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why the code above selects the range between columns E and J for March. For me it worked with the exception that I exchanged the second parameter in max function for 0 (because of the offset you make later):

```
Sub SelectCells()

Dim currentMonth As Single
Dim firstMonth As Single
Dim pastMonths As Single


pastMonths = 6

currentMonth = Month(Date) ' In this case: August
firstMonth = WorksheetFunction.Max(currentMonth - pastMonths, 0)

'select the work file

'Windows("MyScrubbedData.xlsx").Activate
Range("B3").Select

Range(Range("C4").Offset(0, firstMonth), Range("C5").Offset(0, currentMonth - 
1)).Select

End Sub
```